# Activity not staying in the same activity while device rotation

Tags: android, screen-orientation

In my application it is working fine in the portrait. but when i rotate the device it does not remain in the same activity. it goes to the to mainactivity. how make make it remain in the same activity while rotating the device

Comment: Try to add android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" in your <activity> under <application> in AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: thanks brother. its working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` in your `<activity>` under `<application>` in AndroidManifest.xml.

Accept the answer and close the question if this answer is proper.